# Selenium Executable Jar not working in IDE 2021 - 03

Tags: java, selenium

Getting the error while importing the selenium executable jar. I have added the executable jars of selenium and java client 7.5.1 in module path under the library tab. Due to that not able to set capabilities. Please help me with this.

```
package appium;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities; //The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities is not accessible

public class base {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in your source folder?

Comment: Yes I have that, and there is a test too, when I click it it shows
module Test {
 requires okio;
}

Comment: You need to either add selenium to the module-info.java or delete the module-info.java.

Comment: I have created new project without module file but still getting the error 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities is not accessible.

Comment: Is that class part of the API?